# Writing a program that calls two methods to ask the user math questions and displays their amount of questions and incorrect answers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, random, joptionpane

I have a program that reads =

[program instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCMUY.png)

I think I got most of the stuff right but the main thing I'm having issues with is not understanding how to increment the totalWrong global variable with the Wrongs! inside of the loop. Also having trouble with getting the summary method to utilize the global variables.

```
    package practicejoptionpanetwo;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class PracticeJOptionPaneTwo 
    {

        public static int loopCount = 0;
        public static int totalWrong = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) 

        {

         addition();
         summary();    

        } 

            public static void addition()

            {

            int userAnswer, ranNum1, ranNum2, correctAnswer;
            String strUserAnswer;

            Random myRan = new Random();

            int loopCount;
            String strLoopCount;
            strLoopCount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times do you wish to practice addition?");
            loopCount = Integer.parseInt(strLoopCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
            {       
                ranNum1 = myRan.nextInt(10)+1;
                ranNum2 = myRan.nextInt(10)+1;
                correctAnswer = ranNum1 + ranNum2;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem # " + (i+1) );
                strUserAnswer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the sum of " + ranNum1 + " + " + ranNum2 + " =?");
                userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(strUserAnswer);

                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Correct!");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong.");
                }
            }

           }


            public static void summary()

            {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There were " + loopCount + " number of problems generated."); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total number of problems answered wrong were " + totalWrong); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The percentage wrong is " + ((double)totalWrong/(double)loopCount)+ 100 + " %");

            }

}
```

Comment: How about ++totalWrong ?

Comment: Yes that worked! it's now counting the total wrong.

Comment: ah and I just deleted the excess loopCount variable in the addition method and it's now counting those. Last issue is with getting the percentage wrong part fixed